# Dynamic Type in Unmarshal

Tags: json, go, types

I currently having the following problem:

I get a []byte / string via websocket which looks like

```
eventname {"JSON": "data", "In": "different formats"}
```

I split the string by the whitespace between the eventname and the JSON data and, **depending on the eventname**, I want to json.Unmarshal() the JSON data into a specific type or a var of a specific type, to make sure its all type safe.

So I would probably have a map which holds all the possible eventnames and the corresponding type for the JSON data, but im not sure how I would save a type, maybe by reference or by the stringified name?

```
type EventTypeList map[string]*interface{}
```

or

```
type EventTypeList map[string]string
```

So I can lookup if the event is in the EventTypeList and then let the Unmarshal func parse the data into the type from the map.

So basicly instead of the specific type "SpecificData":

```
type SpecificData struct {
    JSON string
    In   string
}

socketData := SpecificData{}
err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &socketData)
```

I want to dynamically create the socketData var by the type from the EventTypeList

```
socketData := [dynamically determine this Type from EventTypeList]{}
```

After I parsed the data into that type, I want to call all listeners for that event and give them the socketData with the right type, so they can work with the expected data.

But im really not sure how I would accomplish this, if this is even possible or if this is even the right way...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: instead of holding types in the map, why dont you have func. like `map[string]func(b []byte) (interface{}, error)`

Comment: @vedhavyas But how would I tell the Unmarshal functions in which type to unmarshal the json data into? I dont want the normal `map[string]interface{}` data to be passed to the callback function and then need to test for every key and every type in the callback itself.

Comment: Ahh okay. Let me think and get back

Comment: one way i could think of is to make all the types implement an interface type and your funcs can return that interface instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Unmarshal an inconsistent JSON field that can be a string \*or\* an array of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092462/how-to-unmarshal-an-inconsistent-json-field-that-can-be-a-string-or-an-array-o)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after reasearching, I think what I wanted to achive is not possible, because the type needs to be know at compile time, as it has been mentioned here:

[Golang: cast an interface to a typed variable dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971895/golang-cast-an-interface-to-a-typed-variable-dynamically)

But I think I can just pass the raw JSON string to the listener callback and Unmarshal the data in that function where the type of the data is known.

Thanks for all contributions!