# How to Unmarshal an inconsistent JSON field that can be a string *or* an array of string?

Tags: json, go

I am having trouble Unmarshalling some Json I don't have control over.
There is one field that 99% of the time is a string but occasionally is an array.

```
type MyListItem struct {
    Date  string `json:"date"`
    DisplayName       string `json:"display_name"`
}

type MyListings struct {
    CLItems []MyListItem `json:"myitems"`
}

var mylist MyListings
err = json.Unmarshal(jsn, &mylist)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Print("JSON:\n%s\n error:%v\n", string(jsn),err)
    return
}
```

Json is as follows:

```
{       
    "date": "30 Apr",
    "display_name": "Mr Smith"
},
{
    "date": "30 Apr",
    "display_name": ["Mr Smith", "Mr Jones"],
}
```

error: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field MyListItem.display_name of type string

Comment: So what type should your final `DisplayName` be?

Comment: If you can't control the JSON you might need to Unmarshal into an interface: https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go (check out the section under decoding arbitrary data)

Comment: @zerkms I will concatenate any DisplayName arrays to be a string joined with '&' character

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse/deserlize a dynamic JSON in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347092/how-to-parse-deserlize-a-dynamic-json-in-golang)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [json.RawMessage](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage) to capture the varying field.

Use the json "-" name to hide the `DisplayName` field from decoder. The application will fill this field after the top-level JSON is decoded.

```
type MyListItem struct {
    Date           string          `json:"date"`
    RawDisplayName json.RawMessage `json:"display_name"`
    DisplayName    []string        `json:"-"`
}
```

Unmarshal the top-level JSON:

```
var li MyListItem
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &li); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Unmarshal the display name depending on the type of the raw data:

```
if len(li.RawDisplayName) > 0 {
    switch li.RawDisplayName[0] {
    case '"':
        if err := json.Unmarshal(li.RawDisplayName, &li.DisplayName); err != nil {
            // handle error
        }
    case '[':
        var s []string
        if err := json.Unmarshal(li.RawDisplayName, &s); err != nil {
            // handle error
        }
        // Join arrays with "&" per OP's comment on the question.
        li.DisplayName = strings.Join(s, "&")
    }
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/wuebjjMt3f3)

Incorporate the above into a for loop to handle `MyListings`:

```
var listings MyListings
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &listings); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
for i := range listings.CLItems {
    li := &listings.CLItems[i]
    if len(li.RawDisplayName) > 0 {
        switch li.RawDisplayName[0] {
        case '"':
            if err := json.Unmarshal(li.RawDisplayName, &li.DisplayName); err != nil {
                // handle error
            }
        case '[':
            var s []string
            if err := json.Unmarshal(li.RawDisplayName, &s); err != nil {
                // handle error
            }
            li.DisplayName = strings.Join(s, "&")
        }
    }
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/zj_x65fw8qv)

If there's more than one place in the data model where a value can be a string or []string, it can be helpful to encapsulate the logic in a type. Parse the JSON data in an implementation of the [json.Unmarshaler](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface.

```
type multiString string

func (ms *multiString) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if len(data) > 0 {
        switch data[0] {
        case '"':
            var s string
            if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            *ms = multiString(s)
        case '[':
            var s []string
            if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            *ms = multiString(strings.Join(s, "&"))
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Use it like this:

```
type MyListItem struct {
    Date        string      `json:"date"`
    DisplayName multiString `json:"display_name"`
}

type MyListings struct {
    CLItems []MyListItem `json:"myitems"`
}

var listings MyListings
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &listings); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/-nuVjhE3uKP)

Here's the code to get the value as a slice of strings instead of as a single string with values joined by &.

```
type multiString []string

func (ms *multiString) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if len(data) > 0 {
        switch data[0] {
        case '"':
            var s string
            if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            *ms = multiString{s}
        case '[':
            if err := json.Unmarshal(data, (*[]string)(ms)); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/5Fdgtz7lXAg).

Comment: Thanks @ThunderCat that did the trick. Very useful to know about json.Rawmessage

Comment: You can make this more self-contained by having MyListItem provide an implementation of `UnmarshalJSON`: https://play.golang.org/p/vXFwQBhYQvR

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative, this builds off of the answer from @ThunderCat but instead of using `json.RawMessage`, uses `interface{}` and a type switch:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type MyListItem struct {
    Date           string      `json:"date"`
    DisplayName    string      `json:"-"`
    RawDisplayName interface{} `json:"display_name"`
}

func (li *MyListItem) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type localItem MyListItem
    var loc localItem
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &loc); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *li = MyListItem(loc)
    switch li.RawDisplayName.(type) {
    case string:
        li.DisplayName = li.RawDisplayName.(string)
    case []interface{}:
        vals := li.RawDisplayName.([]interface{})
        if len(vals) > 0 {
            li.DisplayName, _ = vals[0].(string)
            for _, v := range vals[1:] {
                li.DisplayName += "&" + v.(string)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func test(data string) {
    var li MyListItem
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &li); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(li.DisplayName)
}

func main() {
    test(`
{       
    "date": "30 Apr",
    "display_name": "Mr Smith"
}`)

    test(`
{
    "date": "30 Apr",
    "display_name": ["Mr Smith", "Mr Jones"]
}`)

}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/39QPJTnhiRg)