# Type assertion with type from field of structure

Tags: go, types

Here is a simplified example of what I struggle with:

```
type Dog struct {
    Bark bool
}

func myLogic(i interface{}) {
    newVar = i.(Dog)  // Work fines -> newVar is of type Dog if I passed such type to the function through the interface
    newVar2 = i.(Dog.Bark) // I get an error "type Dog has no method Bark"
}
```

How can I possibly get the type bool from the field Bark through the Dog structure here in order to use it for type assertion ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang: cast an interface to a typed variable dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971895/golang-cast-an-interface-to-a-typed-variable-dynamically)

Comment: `Dog` is a type, `Bark` is a member, not a type.

Comment: Hi guys, I might have not explained what I wanna do well enough. I do not want to acces the Bark method, I wanna access the Bark type, so that if I change some complex model somewhere I my code I won't have to change the type assertion. In summary, I want to do i.(Dog.Bark) instead of i.(bool)

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this.

```
func myLogic(i interface{}) {
    newVar2 = i.(Dog)
    fmt.Println(newVar2.Bark)
}
```

First, cast the interface to Dog type.
Then you can get the Bark value from Dog type (struct)

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `reflect` package

the following code for example which extract the type of `Dog.Bark` and check if input variable has that same type.

```
 package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "reflect"
    )
    
    type Dog struct {
        Bark bool
    }
    
    func testtype(h interface{}) {
        d := Dog{}
        t := reflect.TypeOf(d.Bark)

        if reflect.TypeOf(h) == t {
            fmt.Println("success")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("failed")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried reflect but is does not work here as t is not considered as a type, it gives me the following error "t is not a type" when I tried to type assertion with it => i.(t)

Comment: you can't get that with `reflect.TypeOf`. I was pointing towards the functionality you were looking for, which was to check if given `interface{}` is of a certain type. To do it wihout using `bool` and using the original struct and its members only.

Comment: Then do you know how I can get it ? cause my question was how to get a type usable for type assertion

Comment: using the method above will ensure one thing you won't need to re-write the test every time you change the type of your struct member.