# Get inteface's dynamic value when there is a pointer to integer as dinamic type

Tags: go, reflection, interface

I'm struggling trying to figure out how to "extract" an integer value from a interface that holds a value whose dynamic type is pointer to integer.

You may follow this [ready-to-run](https://play.golang.org/p/aGtuP74gFoE) example in order to fully get the picture of what is problem and my intention.

TD;DR:

For some reason the reflection on a first call to `reflect.ValueOf(value)` over an interface whose dynamic type is pointer to integer, it returns a value whose `Kind()` results in `reflect.Ptr`, when i extract again the "inner" value using  `reflect.ValueOf(value).Elem()` i get another value whose `Kind()` results in `reflect.Struct`. I don't even code any struct, but they appears by their own "magically". So golang may not panic but i don't understand what is happening, probably i lack of some information. I would be very thankful with anyone that explaint me what is going on.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27972247/903998) may work for this case, but it doesn't enlight me. I would expect to have an integer value "behind" the pointer. I don't need to access for modification, i only need to get it.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco thanks for the advice, i have already find it. It doesn't enlight me althought it helps.

Comment: The answer you linked solves your problem. Could you elaborate a bit more about what is not connecting for you?

Comment: i try to explain what i know and what suprises me in the TL;DR; section

Comment: It's struct because when you call `ToCompliantValue` inside the function, you're then not reflecting on the value itself, you're reflecting on a `reflect.Value` value, and `reflect.Value` is a struct.

Comment: You put a pointer to int into the interface, hence you get a pointer to int out of the type switch. If you want the actual int value, you must dereference the pointer, and voila. I think `reflect` is overkill for this problem.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco first Thanks for the time and energy to help me understand and solve my problem. Second if you think i'm overengineering thinks you may show me how do you taclke this issue: I'm converting any value (except Structs and maps for now!) to postgres compliant values, so far i got this:  https://play.golang.org/p/D_rYiavBQPa. Finally  i finally saw that the main problem is that i'm putting `v.Elem()` inside an interface in the second call to `ToCompliantValue` and it is get "wrapped" again in an interface.

Comment: @Victor See this [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_u27tUFWK3-) example. This is what I was trying to explain in my previous comments. If you want to handle a known set of types (e.g., the built-in types), then a type switch like this works great. If you need to handle unknown types (e.g., any user defined types), then you will need `reflect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's struct because when you call `ToCompliantValue` inside the function, you're not passing it the value itself, you're passing a `reflect.Value` value, and `reflect.Value` is a struct. You have to handle it directly instead of trying to use recursion:

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(value)
fmt.Printf("Value is %+v\n", v)
if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    v = v.Elem()
}
switch v.Kind() {
    // ...
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/ndRjXJfj5xV

Comment: thanks for the insight! i get a little confused by reading the internal documentation regarding the `func (v Value) Elem() Value` it says that ` Elem returns the value that the interface v contains or that the pointer v points to.` For start it says "interface v" and v is not an interface type is a Value type.. leaving aside that, i thought that the value contained by whatever entity is "v" is the actual value, in this case a Pointer to integer. I dig a little further this in this example: you may see that everything a get from  `reflect.ValueOf(value)` is a Value but the `Kind()` is different

Comment: the example: https://play.golang.org/p/Mwp5G4jZzr7.. again thanks a lot for the insight given!

Comment: Yes, `Kind` returns the type of the value that the `Value` represents. Even while using reflection, Go is statically typed; `Value` is a concrete type, not a dynamic type based on what it contains.